# while creating radio buttons using ng-repeat & ng-view model value is not getting reflected in controller

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to  render a page using ng-view in that I am using ng-repeat to render my radio buttons and the ng-model which is there not updating my value in controller..

MY HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="role in Roles">
            <input type="radio" ng-model="Role"
             value="role" ng-value="role"
                name="Roles"
                id={{role}}>                
            <span>{{role}}</span>
        </div>
```

MY CONTROLLER

```
 console.log("Moving Forward--"+$scope.Role);
```

on console printing undefined..

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me, however you can set an object on the `$scope` to set your properties which you get when the user interacts as a single data source which will be same when updated from different controllers/sources.

Works fine like the way you do check below example

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);
  
  DefaultController.$inject = ['$scope'];  
  
  function DefaultController($scope) {
    $scope.availableRoles = ['Admin', 'Manager', 'User'];
    $scope.logSelectedRole = logSelectedRole;
    
    function logSelectedRole() {
      console.clear();
      console.log("Moving Forward -- " + $scope.selectedRole);
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController">
    <div ng-repeat="role in availableRoles">
      <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.selectedRole" value="role" ng-value="role" name="Roles" id="{{role}}"/>         <span style="display: inline-block; line-height: 28px;">{{role}}</span>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="logSelectedRole()">Log to console</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Same example using controller aliasing

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);
  
  function DefaultController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.availableRoles = ['Admin', 'Manager', 'User'];
    vm.logSelectedRole = logSelectedRole;
    
    function logSelectedRole() {
      console.clear();
      console.log("Moving Forward -- " + vm.selectedRole);
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="role in ctrl.availableRoles">
      <input type="radio" ng-model="ctrl.selectedRole" value="role" ng-value="role" name="Roles" id="{{role}}"/>         <span style="display: inline-block; line-height: 28px;">{{role}}</span>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="ctrl.logSelectedRole()">Log to console</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check [this](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot) video and the below example about the difference when you create an object on the `$scope` and assign your properties on them instead of assigning directly. I recommend you to use the below approach instead of using `$parent.something` or use controller aliasing syntax.

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);
  
  DefaultController.$inject = ['$scope'];
  
  function DefaultController($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
      selectedRole: undefined
    };
    
    $scope.availableRoles = ['Admin', 'Manager', 'User'];
    $scope.logSelectedRole = logSelectedRole;
    
    function logSelectedRole() {
      console.clear();
      console.log("Moving Forward -- " + $scope.data.selectedRole);
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController">
    <div ng-repeat="role in availableRoles">
      <input type="radio" ng-model="data.selectedRole" value="role" ng-value="role" name="Roles" id="{{role}}"/>         <span style="display: inline-block; line-height: 28px;">{{role}}</span>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="logSelectedRole()">Log to console</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="role in Roles">
            <input type="radio" data-ng-model="Role"
            data-ng-value="role"
            ng-change="Value()"
                name="Roles">               
            <span>{{role}}</span>
        </div>
```

In controller
    $scope.Value=function(){

```
                        console.log("Moving Forward--"+$scope.Role);                                                 
             }
```

Working fine...